# How to get NodeId details from DataValue response in callback of async read operation from OPC UA server using Softing toolkit

Tags: c++, opc, opc-ua

[image shows the uint32 value but i need the NodeId details too, which is "Counter1" as in the NodeId in readAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGSQc.jpg)  I am using Softing OPC UA toolkit to develop a client. With session->readAsync() i try to read value from OPC UA server, the callback method onReadComplete is invoked  with the vector of DataValue requested for, i could get the value from the DataValue but unable to get the NodeId with namespaceIndex, indentifierType, identifier. In Visual Studio debugger these values are Unable to read memory.

read async:

```
std::vector<ReadValueId> readValueId1s;
ReadValueId ReadValueId1;
ReadValueId1.setNodeId(NodeId(2, _T("Counter1")));
ReadValueId1.setAttributeId(EnumAttributeId_Value);
readValueId1s.push_back(ReadValueId1);

// read the variable asynchronously
result = session->readAsync(pRdReq, EnumTimestampsToReturn_Both, 
readValueId1s, 0, pRdReq->getTransId());
```

callback method:

```
void TestSession::onReadComplete(void* requestHandle, EnumStatusCode 
serviceResult, std::vector<DataValue>& values)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        std::wcout << values[i].getValue()->getNodeId().toString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us some piece of code please?

Comment: i have added the code and the debugger screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [OPC UA Specification Part 4 - Services](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/part-4-services/) Chapter 5.10.2 Read

An OPC UA Read Response contains an array of DataValue. Each OPC UA DataValue structure contains

- StatusCode
- SourceTimestamp
- ServerTimestamp
- SourcePicoseconds
- ServerPicoseconds
- **Value**

An OPC UA Value structure contains

- ArrayType (0 in your case = Scalar)
- DataType (6 in your case = OpcUaType_Int32)
- Value (from an Union depending on the ArrayType and the DataType value)

So actually in your case the value is Int32 Variant Union value = 46132370

**Edit**

The order of the DataValue in the ReadResponse DataValue Array match with the order of Read NodeId from the ReadRequest you have sent. You should then save the information before sending the ReadRequest in order to know for which NodeId the DataValue ["X"] is the value.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I figured out that the order of DataValue match with order in the read request.